# Почему не работает Expression Language Java EE?

Tags: java-ee, jsp

на JSP странице через Expression Language ${object.property} пытаюсь вывести параметр name у объекта User который ранее передал через `req.setAttribute("user",user);`.
В дебаге у request - а `req` объект `User` присутствует но на странице получаю `${user.name}`.

Servlet

```
public class TempComtroller  extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = new User();
        req.setAttribute("user",user);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view/start.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }
}
```

JSP Page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jsp Page Start</title>
</head>
<body>
${user.name}
</body>
</html>
```

User.class

```
public class User {
    private String name = "No_Name";
    private String email = "No_Email";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Причина была в неправильной конфигурации web.xml
Правильная конфигурация :

````
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>```
````